# Which one to use Cross Memory Attach or ptrace?

Tags: process, memory, strace, ptrace

I'm trying out ptrace system calls, I just discovered [Cross Memory Attach](https://lwn.net/Articles/453053/) from Christopher Yeoh.

I wonder which one is better in term of performance between Cross Memory Attach and ptrace.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use both -- they're not equivalent. use ptrace() to control the process and process_vm_*() instead of PTRACE_PEEK or POKE.

Comment: you can also use `/proc/PID/mem`, but since there's no multi-pread() or multi-pwrite(), the process_vm_*() funcs are nicer, even if the rationale for their existence is not convincing ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much @mosvy, why process_vm_*() is nicer for read & write than ptrace with PEEK and POKE please ? :)

Comment: I was saying that process_vm_*() are nicer than pread, pwrite, readv, etc on /proc/pid/mem. Their advantage vs ptrace_peekdata or pokedata is obvious -- the latter can only transfer one word at a time. I suggest you try them insyead of doing a dry assessment.